# Magento Multistore, two templates, two menus

Tags: magento

I have a **multistore** Magento setup (Magento 1.7.0.2) and I want to have two different templates for different stores. After installing the second one, menu in the first template disappears. I think this is because of the custom **Menu Module** implemented by the templates.

How to edit the modules to overwrite Magento navigation in two different ways (for two different templates)?

Cheers!

Comment: Did your module multistore ? Also check the correspondence categories and web settings needed for two stores.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RV72F2HH5mM

Answer (score 0):

Upon your description, I guess the problem is caused by default Block, Controller or Model is override by the Menu Module. It's not easy to handle this in the current version of Magento. I can propose a solution with regards on the situation you met.

**Check which class is override**

You may check the config.xml under the Menu Module, the path should be

```
/MAGENT_ROOT/app/code/{local,community}/Custom/Menu/etc/config.xml
```

Check the tags

```
/config/global/models/xxxx/rewrite        # for model rewrite
/config/global/rewrite/xxxx/{from, to}    # for controller rewrite
/config/global/blocks/xxxx/rewrite        # for block rewrite
```

Then you can have a view on what's overrided by the module.

**Create a Store view based options**

```
/MAGENT_ROOT/app/code/{local,community}/Custom/Menu/etc/system.xml
```

Add an option called *Enable the extension*. (Some snippets as following)

```
# the xml should insert into /config/sections/xxxx/groups/general/fields/
<enabled>
    <label>Enable the extension</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</enabled>
```

**Check the classes**

Well programmed should override the default class. So we can use the following logic:

```
if (Mage::getStoreConfig('xxxx/general/enabled') === '1') {
    # the original module logic
} else {
    parent::some_method($_args);
}
```

This is the solution I can propose under my assumption. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

on create the second store just select the same category root or your custom category list for that store and you will have the menu working in the second, third store.

```
System > Manage Stores:
```

Select the `Store Name` that doesn't show you the menu now, and select the default `Root Category *`

Hope this help you.